# How to get wildcard cert from LetsEncrypt and install to several postion?

Tags: lets-encrypt

1. Let'sencrypt cert is used in several software in my vps server: apache,postfix,dovecot.
2. Besides `example.com`,I need one wildcard cert to cover `mail.example.com`,`www.example.com`

Then I tried:

```
acme.sh --install-cert -d *.example.com -d example.com --dns dns_cf --key-file /etc/pki/dovecot/private/*.example.com.key --fullchain-file /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/examplefullchain.cer --fullchain-file /etc/apache2/fullchain.cer --key-file /etc/apache2/*.example.com.key
```

The result is `Domain is not valid:'*.exmaple.com'`
My system is centos 7.4,bash version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu),acme.sh v2.8.0
Thanks inadvence for any solution!

Comment: Can you request a certificate using `-d '*.example.com'` instead (notice the apostrophes)? The asterisk is a special character in bash.

Comment: No,output is `Domain is not valid:'*.example.com'`.

Comment: Which operating system you're using, which version of shell, which version of the `acme.sh` script?

Comment: Any reason for using unreleased (potentially unstable) 2.8 instead of stable 2.7.9?

Comment: I don't know, have you tried it? You should never use unpublished packages anyway. Their download script sucks if you ask me. Or at least the master should always point to the latest stable version of the software.